# Executing Dart File takes too long

Tags: dart

As a newbie in dart dev , I starting by setting up my VS Code for Dart/Flutter .
When I try to run a simple Dart program ( just to check everything works fine printing sum of 2 int 4+6 )

```
PS B:\Flutter> dart .\Sum_Course_Exemple.dart
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building flutter tool... 
Running pub upgrade...
4+6=10
```

These lines takes too long to show the output .
Am I doing something wrong ? why it's taking 3min to show that output for a simple code ?

Comment: You ought to find out why it's showing that error message: errors can take quite a long time to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Flutter or pub is trying to install or upgrade dependencies, but this relies on Git, which you do not have installed.

As a result, the Flutter SDK tries to perform some first-run initialisation every time you run your program, which is why it takes so long each time.

Git can be obtained from [its website](https://git-scm.com/downloads).